# Replace upper case characters with a 1 and lower case with a 0

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a Python code based on a PHP one.
What I'm struggling with is the ternary operator in Python.

As you see in the title, I want to replace the uppercase characters in a string with "1" and the lowercase characters with "0".

```
String1: 00X2I00000ABCDa
Expected result1: 111111111111110
```

PHP Code

```
$bits .= (!is_numeric($char) && $char == strtoupper($char)) ? '1' : '0';
```

[This is the complete PHP script](http://webaugur.com/php-snippets/37-phpsnips-salesforce-id-15-to-18chars.html)

Thank you!

Comment: `"".join(["0" if i.islower() else "1" for i in s])`?

Comment: I am not convinced that the PHP code gets the expected result.

Comment: I suppose you aren't interested in a regex solution?

Comment: the expected result does not meet ur description! if uppercase is X why it is 1 in ur expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
c = "00X2I00000ABCDa"
''.join(map(str, [1 if c.isupper() or c.isnumeric() else 0 for c in a]))
```

Where `c` is your input string

Answer (score 0):

Using `join()`:

```
s = '00X2I00000ABCDa'
print("".join(["1" if x.isupper() or x.isnumeric() else "0" for x in s]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
111111111111110
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your expected result for a single character you could do:

```
bits += '0' if char.islower() else '1'
```

though if you wish, you could also write the conversion of the whole string as a one-liner:

```
bits = ''.join('0' if char.islower() else '1' for char in string1)
```

This gives:

```
111111111111110
```

However, I am not convinced that the PHP code shown in the question actually gives you the expected result. The Python equivalent would be:

```
bits = ''.join('1' if not char.isnumeric() and char == char.upper() else '0'
               for char in string1)
```

roughly equivalent to:

```
bits = ''.join('1' if char.isupper() else '0'
               for char in string1)
```

which gives:

```
001010000011110
```

So take your pick...

(Note: I say only "roughly equivalent" above because of other cases that you might want to consider, e.g. non-alphanumeric characters.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also want the result as a string:

```
string1 = '00X2I00000ABCDa'
result = "".join(["0" if i.islower() else "1" for i in string1])

print(result)
>>> '111111111111110'
```

To break this down:

`"0" if i.islower()` creates a string containing the character `""` if `i` has a method `islower` which returns `True`. Only lower case strings of characters will have this property.

`else "1"` otherwise creates a string containing `"1"`. And we do this for i as each item (single character string) in the string `string1`.

Putting all this inside `[ ]` creates a list of these values:
`['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']`

We then use the `join` method on an empty string `''` to join all the single character strings inside this list into a single string, and assign it to `result`.